# Finding embedding of a molecule dataset

Tags: python, embedding, macaw

Embeddings of a **drug dataset** using macaw (Molecular Autoencoding AutoWorkAround) which is an Accessible Tool for Molecular Embedding and InverseMolecular Design.
After that I convert the embeddings into *pandas* dataframe and the convert it into a *.csv* file which includes class labels of the main dataset.

But when I try to apply the **smote** algorithm on MLP or Logistic Regression Classifier the classification metrices named *precision, recall, F1 score* remains the same that means there is no improvement after applying the smote.

So, I think there is a problem in finding the embeddings. Please help.

The code which I applied, the dataset and the paper from where I got the idea are given below.

My source code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score
from sklearn.svm import SVR

from rdkit import SimDivFilters
from rdkit.Chem import rdMolDescriptors
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
import macaw
print(macaw.__version__)
from macaw import *
from google.colab import files
df=files.upload()
df=pd.read_csv("BBBP.csv")
smiles=df.smiles
print(len(smiles))
mcw = MACAW(random_state=42)
mcw.fit(smiles)
BBBP_embedding=mcw.transform(smiles)
print(BBBP_embedding)
hiv_embedding=pd.DataFrame(BBBP_embedding)
extracted_col=df["p_np"]
hiv_embedding=hiv_embedding.join(extracted_col)
hiv_embedding.to_csv("BBBP_embedding.csv")
from google.colab import files
files.download("BBBP_embedding.csv")
```

Dataset link: https://moleculenet.org/

Paper link: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jcim.2c00229

I expect someone can find the code's mistake and help me to correct it. Thanks!

Comment: You should upload your code as text per [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Please check the meaning of pre-existing tags before using them: `molecule` has nothing to do with chemistry here. Thanks.

Comment: "F1 score remains the same" please post the scores, is it exactly the same or slightly different?